# Plotting Particular Solutions to an ODE in MATLAB

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

I have the ODE $$dy - (y^{2}\sin(x))dx = 0$$
I have found the general solution of this (by transforming it into an exact equation and solving) to be $$y=\frac{1}{\cos(x)+c}$$ if $\cos(x)\neq c$.

If I now have the initial conditions $$y(0)=1$$ and $$y(\pi/2)=a$$ where $a=\pm1/2,\pm2/3,\pm1$, how do I plot these particular solutions in MATLAB?

My main reason for asking is that I get quite a different plot to my lecturer for the case of $y(0)=1$. For reference, the plots are over $0\leq x\leq4\pi$.

I get [image]

Whereas my lecturer gets [image]

Comment: For me, they are the same! You surely have noticed that the only difference is in the "erasing" of some asymptotes in your lecturer's solutions...This is classical and probably due to a smaller (then best adapted) step in your application of ode45, or equivalent.

Comment: I thought that they were similar, but I'm not sure how to change mine to look like my lecturer's.

Comment: Yours are perfect ! Keep them...

Comment: Will do. Thanks JeanMarie!